# Using Dask in EC2 instances throws "Couldn't gather 1 keys... "

Tags: amazon-ec2, dask

I launched a couple of EC2 instances, installed dask with conda, started the scheduler and worker in their respective instances and the scheduler is able to receive a connection from the worker. However, after initiating a client and gathering the result (e.g. `x.result()`) throws the error

> WARNING - Couldn't gather 1 keys, rescheduling and the connection between scheduler and worker is terminated.

This is pretty much the same error in this issue [2095](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2095) and fixed in [1278](https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/1278). Unfortunately, it is clear how to fix the issue with the new flags.

This is what my session looks like:

**Scheduler - Terminal**

```
>>> from dask.distributed import Client
>>> client = Client('<domain-scheduler>:8786')
>>> def inc(x):
...   return x + 1
...
>>> x = client.submit(inc, 10)
>>> x.result()
distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 1 keys, rescheduling {'inc-17ff1aa09aeed9c364fc31df7522511e': ('tcp://172.30.3.63:38971',)}
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/dask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 190, in result
    raiseit=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/dask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 652, in sync
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/dask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 273, in sync
    e.wait(10)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/dask-env/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 614, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/dask-env/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

**Scheduler - dask-scheduler**

```
(dask-env) ubuntu@ip-172-30-3-136:~$ dask-scheduler --host <domain-scheduler>:8786 --bokeh-port 8080
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Clear task state
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   Scheduler at:   tcp://172.30.3.136:8786
distributed.scheduler - INFO -       bokeh at:         172.30.3.136:8080
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Local Directory:      /tmp/scheduler-TX9nqO
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://172.30.3.63:38971
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, tcp://172.30.3.63:38971
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Receive client connection: Client-b5d903b5-8620-11e8-8a4c-06a866fbd474
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Remove worker tcp://172.30.3.63:38971
distributed.core - INFO - Removing comms to tcp://172.30.3.63:38971
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Lost all workers
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.30.3.63:38971'], inc-17ff1aa09aeed9c364fc31df7522511e
None
^Cdistributed.scheduler - INFO - End scheduler at u'tcp://<domain>:8786'
```

**Worker - dask-worker**

```
(dask-env) ubuntu@ip-172-30-3-63:~$ dask-worker --host <domain-worker>:8786 <domain-scheduler>:8786
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://172.30.3.63:8786'
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:    tcp://172.30.3.63:38971
distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:    tcp://172.30.3.63:38971
distributed.worker - INFO -              bokeh at:           172.30.3.63:8789
distributed.worker - INFO -              nanny at:           172.30.3.63:8786
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to: tcp://<domain-schedule>:8786
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                          1
distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                    1.04 GB
distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /home/ubuntu/dask-worker-space/worker-EnKL22
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -         Registered to: tcp://<domain-scheduler>:8786
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
distributed.worker - INFO - Stopping worker at tcp://172.30.3.63:38971
distributed.worker - WARNING - Heartbeat to scheduler failed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Closing Nanny at 'tcp://172.30.3.63:8786'
distributed.dask_worker - INFO - End worker
```

As you can see, the session is terminated after running `x.result()`. I also tried to include `--listen-address`, `--contact-address` without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to give `dask-scheduler` and `dask-worker` specific open ports to use instead of allowing them to select other random ports. The commands should look like this:

**Scheduler**

```
dask-scheduler --host <domain-scheduler> --port 8786 --bokeh-port <open-port>
```

**Workers**

```
dask-worker --host <domain-worker> <domain-scheduler>:8786 --worker-port 8786
```

**Terminal**

```
client = Client('tcp://<domain-scheduler>:8786')
```

Comment: What is a <domain-worker> in this case? Is it IP address of the worker? Ot its name?

Comment: I think I used the domain name of the instance running that worker, although an IP address should also work.

Answer (score 1):

When I have had this issue in the past it has been because the scheduler is unable to reach the worker. If you run `curl <domain-worker>:8789` from the scheduler is bokeh html returned? I'm guessing it's not an you need to change something with your network setup in AWS.

Comment: Thank you for response. I believe there was communication between scheduler and worker because bokeh was displaying the worker and receiving information until gathering results. In the dask-scheduler snippet there are a couple of lines referring to the connection : `Receive client connection` and `Starting established connection`. It is also important to point out that the heartbeat failure message occurs only after `x.gather()`.

Comment: Yeah for me when I had this issue the worker was able to be reached by the scheduler and so things would startup correctly but then when the scheduler would try to send a job to the worker this exact thing would happen. I would still say check the curl and that the ip you are replacing <domain-worker> with is correct :)

Comment: Interesting. I will take a look again and run curl as you said.

Comment: I just checked what I'm using and I am not including a port in the host option when starting the worker. Try without it.

Comment: I just launched a couple of instances and tested without port in the worker `dask-worker --host <domain-worker> <domain-scheduler>:8786`. However, I still get the same error. Unfortunately, `curl <domain-worker>:8080` (8080 because I changed the port for bokeh) actually returns the corresponding html file.

Comment: Any other suggestion based on your configuration? Maybe something unusual in the `INFO` statements for worker/scheduler ? I'm actually using domain names instead of IPs and running on VPC

Comment: I figure out what was the problem. I needed to force `dask-scheduler` and `dask-worker` to use an open port instead of randomly selecting other port. I will post an answer to describe each command. Thank you for your help!